# How do I get OneDrive to return to paused sync during metered connections?

Tags: sync, onedrive

On my Windows 10 laptop, when I connect to a metered network, OneDrive pauses sync which is absolutely what I want in general. However sometimes I want to connect and sync for some specific reason even though I'm on a metered connection. I can do this by just resuming sync in OneDrive. After the sync is complete, I want to return OneDrive to the state it was previously, i.e. paused while on a metered connection. How do I do this? I only see options to pause sync for a 2, 8 or 24 hour fixed period, which is not really what I want to do.

Comment: @Rambound the option is still enabled in OneDrive Settings even after manually resuming the sync

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand your question. If it's paused then the system tray icon shows a grey pause icon and when you click on it there is a big banner at the top saying "OneDrive is paused. Your files are not currently syncing". So it's easy to tell it's paused. As I mentioned in my original post, it pauses as desired when I connect to a metered connection. I am not sure if I have answered your question as I didn't really get what you're asking.

Comment: "apparently, you want a way to indefinitely pause OneDrive synchronization without being on your metered connection" - not sure what I have said to make you think this. I never asked about that. I am not sure how my question is confusing. in the scenario I described, I am on a metered connection. I have no problems with non-metered connections, and never asked about them. on a non-metered connection, my sync doesn't pause, which is exactly the behaviour I want.

Comment: Have you tried to ucheck the box of "automatically pause sync when this device is on a metered network" and then tick back? Besides, I suggest you locate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive`, check the data of **UserSettingMeteredNetworkEnabled**. make sure it is **0**. Or you may try to [reset OneDrive client](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reset-onedrive-34701e00-bf7b-42db-b960-84905399050c).

Comment: @Emily - yes, I have tried unticking and then ticking back. regarding that registry value, it's set to 0 if the box is unticked, and 1 if the box is ticked. so usually would be set to 1 for me. I believe resetting OneDrive involves restarting OneDrive as one of the steps. if I restart OneDrive, it behaves normally. is there no way to fix it without restarting OneDrive?